# Cloning apps on iOS

Tags: ios, applications, xcode, development, certificate

For some reasons I want to get two similar apps on my iPhone (in fact not similar — different versions). I have already installed this app from AppStore, and I have an IPA file of this app but of another version, and I want to install it as clone

I tried to edit `Info.plist` file and I’ve changed BundleID in it (com.company.appname format). After all I’ve compressed `Payload` folder to ZIP file and renamed it to IPA

But, when I tried to install it, after the installation process finished, it said something like “cannot install  because it could not be checked its integrity”

So what should I do to install it? I haven’t account in developers.apple.com but I really need to “clone” the app

iPhone isn’t jailbroken, and I’m using the website to install apps because the Mac is too old and does not support Xcode version compatible with iOS 14

Comment: I believe the only way to do this is by jailbreaking your device.  Is your iPhone jailbroken?

Comment: As far as I know, this isn't possible on ios / iPadOS unless you have the source code of the app - [Running Your App in the Simulator or on a Device](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/running-your-app-in-the-simulator-or-on-a-device). (It may be possible if you Jailbreak your device.)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by changing the bundle ID in the Info.plist (as you have already done) - and then resigning the app using the `codesign` tool that comes with Xcode. This is the crucial step that makes it possible for the app to pass the integrity test.

The easiest way to do that is to have a developer account with Apple, but you can also do it a free account. However, you'll have to resign the app every week - otherwise it expires.

Comment: Can you please tell more about it? I've been trying to sign it for days and I have no results